# Multiple COALESCE in GROUP_CONCAT - is showing value if only first column isn't null

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

Two table's `purchase` and `sales` 's column `date` column has been concatenated as `date` row.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(purchase.date,',',sales.date) AS date
```

But both of them can be blank, according to data input.
So I have concatenated as

```
GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(purchase.date,''),',',COALESCE(sales.date,''))AS date
```

Here, why if `purchase.date` is empty and `sales.date` has value, `sales.date` column is also fetched as empty ? but in case of `purchase.date`, value is shown even if `sales.date` is empty.

I mean my code is not working for second column of `GROUP_CONCAT`. Second column value is only showed if first one is not empty.

I tried with

```
GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(purchase.date,',',sales.date),'')AS date

GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(purchase.date,',',sales.date,'')AS date
```

but still second column is showing null though it has value. if I move `sales.date` in first position, it shows value.

Here is fiddle. `date` shows value because, sales.date is in first position, `date1` returns empty because `sales.date` is in second position.

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df5e6c/5)

Comment: `it is working fine` ... _what_ is working fine?  You never showed us any sample data or expected output.  Please include these.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for advice. Let me add example

Comment: Also, why are you using `GROUP_CONCAT` here?  Can you show us your query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, please see updated post and `Sql Fiddle.`

Comment: I see nothing unexpected yet I still don't really know what you want here.  Showing more realistic sample input plus the current _and_ expected output would really help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I just want to know why my second `sql queries` returning null, why it doesn't return result as `first one`. No more difference between both queries, same table, same value in rows, only position in `Group_Concat` determining to return value or not ?

Comment: `COALESCE(purchase.date,',',sales.date)` will return `,` if the purchase date be `NULL`, hence the second query returns comma.  The first query returns a date because `COALESCE` always returns the first non `NULL` value in its list.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, so what can I do if second one has value and first one is empty in the list while using `COALESCE`. Based on my example `purchase.date` is empty, but `sales.date` is not, and `COALESCE` returning `,` instead of `sales.date` value, I need to return `sales.date` even if `purchase.date` is empty. Isn't it possible from `COALESCE` ?

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be really helpful here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, First fall Thanks to you, you are continuously spending your time regarding my problem. I am feeling awkward to my weakness that I can't clarify clearly. in clear and plain sight, my desired output is -  `date1` (in my `Sql queries`) should return value like `date` or to be more precise it should return exact value `2019-01-06` which is `sales.date` value, but currently it returns `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not do what you seem to want it to do:

```
COALESCE(sales.date, ',', purchase.date)
```

`COALESCE()` returns the first of the three values that is not `NULL`, so you will never get `purchase.date`:  `','` is never `NULL`.

You basically want:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(purchase.date, ',', sales.date) AS date
```

However, you have learned that `CONCAT()` -- and even this implicit concatenate -- return `NULL` if any of the values are `NULL`.  One solution is individual `COALESCE()` -- as in your answer.  I cannot reproduce your problem.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2de5a7674b8dd027c46122857822579) is an example of the code working.

Or, you can use `CONCAT_WS()` (although you miss the separator):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', sales.date, purchase.date))
```

Comment: `CONCAT_WS` the best way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure only `COALESCE` is enough here, as @TimBiegeleisen said - `COALESCE` always returns the first non NULL value in its list. So I apply `CASE` condition

```
  CASE
    WHEN purchase.date IS NULL THEN GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(sales.date,'')) 
    WHEN sales.date IS NULL THEN GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(purchase.date,'')) 
    WHEN purchase.date !='' AND sales.date !='' THEN GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(purchase.date,',',sales.date),'')
  END AS date1
```